# How to copy csv files from one directory to another in R recursively

Tags: r

I am able to copy the the files/subdirectories using the code below, but I want to copy the csv files only.

```
dir.create(new_directory)
file.copy(from = old_directory, to = new_directory, recursive = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this?

```
file.copy(from = "old_path/*.csv", to ="new_path/", recursive = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
fls <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
file.copy(fls,
          to = "new_directory", recursive = TRUE,
          overwrite = TRUE, copy.mode = TRUE, copy.date = FALSE)
```